# I cannot get the program to repeat output in an ordered manner

Tags: java

I want to design a program which scales strings. if string d = "abc\ndef\nghi",horizontal scalling=2,vertical scalling=2, then scaleObj.scale(d,2,2)/*defined below*/ should output "aabbcc\naabbcc\nddeeff\nddeeff\ngghhii\ngghhii".

```
//output

aabbcc
aabbcc
ddeeff
ddeeff
gghhii
gghhii
```

ive have a problem which ive defined below:

```
//MainSix.java

public class MainSix{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scale scaleObj = new Scale();
        System.out.println(scaleObj.scale("abc\ndef",2,3));
    }

}

class Scale {

    public static String scale(String strng, int k, int v) {

        //Horizontal Scalling -k
        String s=strng.replaceAll(".", repeat("$0",k));

        //Verical Scalling
        String y = repeat(s,v);

        return y;

    }
    public static String repeat(String str, int times){
        return new String(new char[times]).replace("\0", str);
    }
}
```

When i Compile this i get output

```
aabbcc
ddeeffaabbcc
ddeeffaabbcc
ddeeff

//aabbcc\nddeeffaabbcc\n\nddeeffaabbcc\nddeeff
```

How can i get output

```
aabbcc
aabbcc
aabbcc
ddeeff
ddeeff
ddeeff

//aabbcc\naabbcc\n\naabbcc\nddeeffddeeff\nddeeff
```

Please modify this existing code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want abc\ndef to be equal to aabbcc\nddeeff if the scale is set to 2.

You could split the string into token(chars), then replace each char with it self times the scale factor.

a would be replaced with aa, b => bb, c => cc, etc

In the example below i just create a new string with the output, instead of replacing values in the input (its mostly preference).

```
int scale = 2;
String s = "abc", ss = "";
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) { 
  for (int i = 0; i < scale; i++) {
    ss += c;
  }
}
System.out.println(ss); //ss = aabbcc
```

**EDIT1:**

```
int scale = 2, rpt = 3;
String s = "abc\ndef", ss = "";
for (String t : s.split("\n")) { //Word loop
  for (int j = 0; j < rpt; j++) { //Repeat loop
    for (char c : t.toCharArray()) { //Char loop
      for (int i = 0; i < scale; i++) { //Scale loop
        ss += c;
      }
    }
    ss += "\n";
  }
}
System.out.println(ss); 
/*
aabbcc
aabbcc
aabbcc
ddeeff
ddeeff
ddeeff
*/
```

Comment: I ddnt quite catch that. Can you do it practically?

Comment: @prog_tk better? :)

Comment: nop. All i wanted was for you to output this
    
    //aabbcc\naabbcc\naabbcc\nddeeff\nddeeff\nddeeff

Comment: It only works for horizontal scaling. What about vertical scaling?

Comment: @prog_tk How about now?

Comment: @prog_tk Thank you. Now if you don't mind me asking, would you use this for? o.0

Comment: @prog_tk also, if you feel happy with my answer, please press the check mark next to my answer. This lets everyone else know that the question has been answered.

Comment: How to remove \n at end of ouput? i mean at the very end of execution

Comment: @prog_tk ss = ss.substring(0, ss.length()-1);